# How to structure a splunk query to generate a count of events where the field is either null or not null?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm working with some access logs that may or may not have a user_name field. I don't need to do anything fancy, I'd just like to generate a single query that returns a stats table containing a count of events where this field is either null or not null. For example, my log is structured like this:

```
<timestamp><field1><field2><user_name><field4>
```

For anonymous connections, user_name is not logged, so these values are null. I can get all of the non-null values easily enough:

`<base_query> user_name="*" | stats count`

This gives me a nice table of the non-null user_name field:

```
count
------
812093
```

I can also get a count of the null fields with a little more work, but this seems messy:

```
<base_query> | fillnull user_name value=NULL| search user_name=NULL | stats count
```

And then I get a count of entries with a null user_name field.

```
count
-----
31215
```

However, what I'm really looking for is a single query that combines both of these into a single stats table, ideally:

```
not_null | null
----------------
812093   | 31215
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function "isNull(field)" , you can use to evaluate that and then count

```
index=indxname search_condition
| eval countByFieldExists=if(isnull(field),"notExist","Exists") 
| stats count by countByFieldExists
```

Something like this should work for you